# Authentication problem in SP web application 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, web-application

I have created a web application and then site collection by using my custom template site definition. Its created successfully. But when I access my application I get authentication dialog box for entering user name and password. I entered correct username like domain\username and correct password. The user name and password are 100% correct because I can login with these credentials to other web applications. 
The problem is that, I clicked many times (10 or more times) on OK button on authentication dialog, but it never goes and appear again and again. It even does not show any error code like 401 un-authorized etc.

Any idea what's wrong??

Comment: Share the authentication type for the web application. Is it based out of NTML/Kerberos or Claims/FBA ?

Comment: Is the site in your local intranet or trusted sites zones? Have you edited the BackConnectionHostNames or DisableLoopBackCheck registry keys? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. Open Sites
3. Open your Site
4. Open Authentication
5. Click on Windows Authentication and click under Actions on "Providers..."
6. Compare it to your working Site's

If you don't use Kerberos than remove it from the providers list.
If you don't need anonymous access then disable "Anonymous Authentication"

If you are on a server be sure that you add the site to your local intranet in the IE security settings.

[image: iis]